# Hide non-significant data in Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts

Is there a way to tell excel to not display non-significant series in a chart?

Let's say I have a hundred numbers, having the sum of the the last 90 being less than one of the top 5. I'd like to draw a pie chart with the bottom 90 not shown, or shown as a "others" slice.

Is there a simple chart option or formula I can use? Would I need to get an Excel update?

Comment: This is a Super User question - it is about general use of charts in Excel as opposed to programming. Voted to close.

Comment: @brettdj: true, I asked to move it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good question because the underlying issue is about best practice: separating data from presentation. Excel cannot decide what is "significant", but you can. Why not add something to your data that indicates "significance"? This can be as simple as "yes" or "no", or maybe a granular variable from 0 to 100 where less than 5 means "insignificant". This can generally be accomplished with formulae; the exact method depends on your requirements.

Then, set up a presentation worksheet where you aggregate the data via your method of choice (sumif, pivot table, structured references, etc.) and include the significance attribute. Then, base your chart on the presentation layer. You don't need to actually include the significance attribute in your chart, but you can leverage it in the aggregation.

All this takes a little extra work--but only a little--and it is highly customizable and maintainable.